# Troubleshooting error 503 on Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am running a container on google cloud run. For each request a new instance is started. The requests need around 15 minutes to get processed. I modified the default timeout and everything is working fine. But sometimes, around 10% of the request, I get an error

> The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or
> connection to the instance had an error. Additional troubleshooting
> documentation can be found at:
> https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#timeout-503

When I re-run the exact same request, I get no errors. I tried to put try catch every where, but I am not able to figure out what is happening. I checked the CPU, memory usage ... Everything looks fine, he maximum reached is 50%. Any advice on how can I get more information about the problem?

Comment: The documentation link you include provides good guidance. You should use Cloud Logging (as suggested) to check the request, stderr/out logs. You may want to check [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/error-reporting) too.

Comment: Adding on to what DazWilkin commented, that documentation page should be the starting point to solve this issue. Have you tried looking at those possible causes? Can you also post details about the container you are running (language, dockerfile)?

Comment: how did you manage to resolve this?